# Android GPS : How can I get satellites number in use from NMEA?

Tags: android, gps, nmea

I got the NMEA string with android. but I don't know how can I get the satellites number in use, with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read `GGA` field from your nmea string. It provides you the *Number of satellites being tracked*.

`GGA` - essential fix data which provide 3D location and accuracy data,

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
```

Where:

```
     GGA          Global Positioning System Fix Data
     123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC
     4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N
     01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E
     1            Fix quality: 0 = invalid
                               1 = GPS fix (SPS)
                               2 = DGPS fix
                               3 = PPS fix
                   4 = Real Time Kinematic
                   5 = Float RTK
                               6 = estimated (dead reckoning) (2.3 feature)
                   7 = Manual input mode
                   8 = Simulation mode
     08           Number of satellites being tracked <-- this is what you want
     0.9          Horizontal dilution of position
     545.4,M      Altitude, Meters, above mean sea level
     46.9,M       Height of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84
                      ellipsoid
     (empty field) time in seconds since last DGPS update
     (empty field) DGPS station ID number
     *47          the checksum data, always begins with *
```

you can then use `String::split()` method to read the number of satellites being tracked.

Comment: I think GPS of android doesn't use all GGA's satelites number ... I think this number is the count of all satellites that phone see them (maybe dosen't use all of them). how I can give just the number of satellites that phone uses them to get my coordinate?

Comment: @jion, you may need to read this, http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea, this is what it says "7    = Number of satellites in use [not those in view]"

Comment: I read in other document that 7th of GPGGA is all satellites that GPS see... it return 10 or 11 ... I don't think it is number of satellites in use! :|

Comment: you can see all NMEA Frame composition in the following link http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/